# Problems with Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter on HP ProBook 4330s on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hp, atheros

- Hardware is HP ProBook 4330s
- Software is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

A few days ago all of sudden WiFi adapter stopped working.

The Settings UI says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

Some CLIs say

```
chuck@jones:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
      Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [103c:1461]
      Kernel driver in use: ath9k
      Kernel modules: ath9k
25:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no

chuck@jones:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for chuck: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 74:e5:43:bc:ff:06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-64-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:d4700000-d470ffff

chuck@jones:~$ uname -a
Linux jones 4.15.0-64-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 13:16:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

chuck@jones:~$ iwconfig
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Could it be the related to latest Ubuntu software updates? or a possible crash of old hardware?
How does one troubleshoot such question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your adapter is blocked by `rfkill`. On HP laptops this happens. These are the steps to fix it:

1. Make sure there is no hardware wireless switch on your laptop and turn it on if it exists.
2. Check BIOS for wireless options and enable it. Try to reset BIOS to defaults if you don't have a wireless option.
3. If nothing helps, blacklist the HP platform driver by running in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
   ```

and reboot.